# What is the quotient space $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces

What is the quotient space $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2)$ and more generally how do I determine such spaces (if possible include some reference). Such quotients appear a lot in algebraic geometry and I struggle to understand what these spaces are and "look like". Can you provide a couple of examples?

Note that I am a physicist lacking formal training in abstract algebra. I just want to understand these quotient spaces made out of rings modded out with some polynomials.

Comment: It's the set of distinct polynomial functions in three variables, defined on the subspace of $\Bbb C^3$ given by $x^2+y^2=0$.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Every polynomial in three variables with complex coefficients gives an element of $\Bbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2)$.  If $f$ and $g$ are two such polynomials and $f-g$ is the zero function on the hypersurface $x^2+y^2=0$ then $f$ and $g$ represent the same element in $\Bbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are considering is the function field determined by a variety. In your case, you are considering the variety determined by $x^2 + y^2$, so the function field is naturally $\mathbf{C}(x,y,z)$, where $x,y,z$ are transcendental subject to the relation $x^2 + y^2 = 0$. By looking for the key term "function field" either in common algebraic textbooks (Hartshorne is my reference) or online, you should be able to find a plethora of supplemental material. You should note that this has origins in complex analysis where the function field is just meromorphic functions. Using this fact, you have a natural generalization in scheme theory, namely considering sheaf of meromorphic functions which Hartshorne discusses in great detail in Chapter 2.

Answer (score 5):

Geometrically it is defined by equation $x^2 + y^2=0$ in three dimensional space $\mathbb{C}^3$. Notice $x^2+y^2 =(x+iy)(x-iy)$. So it is the Union of two (complex) plane given by equations $x+iy=0$ and $x-iy=0$

Algebraically, it is the same as $\mathbb{C} [x,y,z]$, besides that when you see $x^2+y^2$ you replace it by $0$

Answer (score 0):

> I struggle to understand what these spaces are and "look like".

Take the union of two transversely intersecting planes in 3-dimensional **real** space, such as $x=0$ and $y=0$.  This is visualizable.  Now allow complex coordinates.

This is equivalent to the space in the question, up to a linear change of coordinates (though the linear changes of variable will have complex coefficients).